# Show username in route (URL) Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am working on a MVC application of ASP.NET and a requirement is to show a username in the URL after the user logs in to the site.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you are working on?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I've understood your question correctly - I apologise if I haven't.

**Create a custom RouteConstraint**

In my example I am checking the URL matches the logged in user's username. If the usernames match then the route is valid and the index action on the home controller will be invoked.

If the username is heymega..

http://localhost:48735/heymega/ would be valid

http://localhost:48735/chris/ would be invalid

```
public class UserNameRoute : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, System.Web.Routing.Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {

        //Get the username from the URL
        var username = values["username"].ToString();

        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //Compare the username to the logged in user
            return httpContext.User.Identity.Name == username;

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Define your route which will support the contraint**

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserNameRoute",
            url: "{username}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { username = new UserNameRoute() }
        );
```